# MongoDB update a specific nested field

Tags: mongodb

Hi I am trying to update nested filed , but couldn't able to do so.
Here is the sample data,

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "632ec4128f567511dcd80ed9"
  },
  "company_id": 1,
  "contact_id": 1001,
  "roles_to_be_accepted": {
    "ROLE#04": {
      "assigned_data": {
        "assigned_3HFui": {
          "is_idle": false,
          "send_for_acceptance_date": 1664009233,
          "action_date": ""
        },
        "assigned_b1J9t": {
          "is_idle": false,
          "send_for_acceptance_date": 1664009233,
          "action_date": ""
        }
      }
    },
    "ROLE#02": {
      "assigned_data": {
        "assigned_uPJI1": {
          "is_idle": false,
          "send_for_acceptance_date": 1664009233,
          "action_date": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

Now I want to update that `is_idle` field to true. I have tried in this way

```
let query = { contact_id: 1, company_id: 1001};
const db = this.client.db("dbname");
const col= db.collection("collection_name");
col.update(query, {
          '$set': { "roles_to_be_accepted.assigned_data.is_idle": true }
        });
```

Comment: you missed the `ROLE#04` property and `assigned_3HFui` property, if you want to update the first object then it should be `"roles_to_be_accepted.ROLE#04.assigned_data.assigned_3HFui.is_idle": true`.

Comment: @turivishal Thank you for the reply, actually ROLE#04 and assigned_3HFui both fields are dynamic. Like Role#* and assigned_*

Comment: Okay, there is no straight way to update all the objects without specifying the property name, you can try update with aggregation pipeline, but it is a totally expensive operation if this is a frequent query. I would suggest you improve your schema design if this is the initial phase of your project.

Comment: @turivishal thanks, no this won't be a frequent query at all. I have checked the aggregation pipeline but is there any manual approach to updating something like that? 
1. Fetch the data using the given company and contact
2. loop through the data and update only that field? is it possible to do so?

Comment: Yes it is possible, you can execute 2 queries first is to find a document and the second is to update it.